# sessionStorage displays undefined in IE11?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on web related applications.When i try to display sessionStorage item it returns "undefined".

IE settings also changed but still i am getting same.

Login.html page:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var currentDate = new Date,
       dformat = [(currentDate.getMonth() + 1),
                   currentDate.getDate(),
                   currentDate.getFullYear()].join('/') +
                   ' ' +
                 [currentDate.getHours(),
                   currentDate.getMinutes(),
                   currentDate.getSeconds()].join(':');

        function unicsession(length) {
            var chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
            var sess = "";
            for (var x = 0; x < length; x++) {
                var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
                sess += chars.charAt(i);
            }
            return sess;
        }

        function generate() {
            var intime = dformat;
            sessionStorage.setItem("logintime", intime);
            var username = document.getElementById("Username").value;
            sessionStorage.setItem("username", username);
            var unisession = unicsession(5);
            sessionStorage.setItem("unisession", unisession);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input id="Username" type="text" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="home.htm" onclick="generate()">Click here</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

home.htm page code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var getid = sessionStorage.getItem("username");
        var logintimes = sessionStorage.getItem("logintime");
        var unicsessionid = sessionStorage.getItem("unisession");
        var currentDate = new Date,
       outformat = [(currentDate.getMonth() + 1),
                   currentDate.getDate(),
                   currentDate.getFullYear()].join('/') +
                   ' ' +
                 [currentDate.getHours(),
                   currentDate.getMinutes(),
                   currentDate.getSeconds()].join(':');
        function Getout() {
            alert("Login Id: " + getid + " ; login Time: " + logintimes+" ; Unic Session-Id : "+unicsessionid+" ; Logout Time : "+outformat);
        }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="logout" type="button" value="Logout" onclick="Getout()"/>
</body>
</html>
```

When i click on login page it redirect to home page and after click on logout button in home page it displays undefined.

How can i resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 1):

`sessionStorage` is not avialable from IE if you access your files via your local filesystem. Use any local server to serve your scripts as http